# Design of a News system

Tags: c#, algorithm, database-design

I have an application for a client who enters News (News has a category) and they are asking that some of the news they want to promote to front page and keep it there for a user configured time. There are news and they can enter more news, but only the one that they qualify as the front page news will be shown per category.

I was thinking that I add a bit field (IsPromotedToHeadline) to database table and a DateTime Field (DisplayUntil) then I can query the News table for the entry that s `Datetime.Now > DisplayUntil and IsPromotedToHeadLine == true and Category == category`. Problem with this would be `DateTime.Now` is greater than Many News.

How can I resolve this?

or do you have a better idea to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should query for the entry that should be shown on the front page (the one who has a `DisplayUntil` value that's *greater than* the current date), instead. This way, as long as there is only one promoted item in each category, you'll only have one item that fulfills the query, and you can show that news item on the page.

Comment: but then i dont need a DisplayUntil field I can have single bit field that will be shown in the front page. and this bit can be set by admin. what do u think?

Comment: You said in the op that you already have a `DisplayUntil` and a bit field. If you want it to stay on the front page until the user changes the settings, then just query for the entry that `IsPromotedToHeadline` without worrying about the current date.

Comment: yeah, I can do that, do u think that s a good approach? or would u do something else to solve this?

Comment: It depends on what your client wants. Do they want to set an expiry date for the front page news item, or do they want to expire it themselves, manually? If they want it to expire automatically, then you'll need both a bit field and a date, otherwise you only need a bit field.